# "You are true!" VS " You are right!"

Tags: word-usage

> P1: What is the Earth's highest mountain in the world?
>
> P2: Everest?
>
> P1: You are true! It's Mount Everest.

VS

> P1: What is the Earth's highest mountain in the world?
>
> P2: Everest?
>
> P1: You are right! It's Mount Everest.

Are both versions acceptable or not? Is one of these preferred? If yes, why?

Comment: The Earth's Xest ... in the world is redundant, since the Earth and the world are the same thing; either *the Earth's Xest* or *the Xest in the world* suffices.

Comment: @StoneyB One Martian said to another, "You are the tallest native Martian I know, but what is the Earth's tallest Martian in the world?"

Comment: @Jay But in that case you are speaking of two worlds, and *the* is no longer appropriate.

Comment: @StoneyB Well of course I was being whimsical. In the context above "Earth" and "world" refer to the same place and are indeed redundant. But to pretend it's a serious discussion: The word "the" doesn't imply that this is the only one in existence. Consider: One American said to another, "There are many tall people here from other nations, but who is the tallest Briton presently in the country?" "The country" would be understood to mean "America", and it is perfectly normal to use "the" in such a context. PS The sentence in my previous post was written hastily and is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"You are right" is correct.

In context, you are not trying to say that the PERSON is true, but that what he SAID is true. You could say, "That statement is true" or "What you said is true", etc. But not "You are true."

There is a slightly archaic expression "you are true" meaning "you are living up to your commitment". This is most commonly used in reference to marriage vows. Like, "Oh darling, if you marry me, I will always be true to you" meaning "I will never have an affair with someone else". It is also used for other commitments, like "The senator rejected the bribe and remained true to his oath of office", or in general "He stayed true to his promise."

Comment: Yes - but equally, *"You are **correct**"* is ***right*** too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, you're good there!